# Distributions induced by (weighted) random walks on the integer lattice

Tags: random-walks, markov-chains, graph-theory, na.numerical-analysis

Consider an integer lattice $\mathbb{Z}^2$ where grid points are separated by a distance $h$.  Loosely speaking, a random walk of length $k$ is a sequence of lattice points $(x_1,\cdots,x_k)$ generated by starting out at the origin and repeatedly moving to one of four immediate neighbors with equal probability $\frac{1}{4}$.  Let $P_k: \mathbb{Z}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ denote the probability that a random walk of length $k$ ends at a given lattice point, and consider the distribution

$$ P = \sum_{k=0}^\infty w_k P_k $$

where $\sum_{k=0}^\infty w_k = 1$.  We can interpret $P$ as the probability that our walk ends at a given lattice point, given that we chose to take a path of length $k$ with probability $w_k$.

It is clear that the behavior of $P$ depends heavily on the choice of weights $w_k$.  For instance, if we set $w_n=0$ for all $n$ above some fixed index $N$, then the support of $P$ is of course contained in a finite $\ell_1$-ball around the origin.  Similarly, if the weights $w_k$ decay very rapidly then for any fixed $n$ the $n$th term will dominate the sum of the remaining terms and again the distribution $P$ will depend primarily on the $\ell_1$ distance to the origin, i.e., the distribution will be sort of ``diamond-shaped.'' (To give at least one concrete example, let $w_k = (4t)^k/(1+4t)^{k+1}$ and consider what happens as $t$ goes to zero.)  For weights that decay *less* rapidly, I hear a lot of folklore about how you get something that looks vaguely Gaussian (hence, not diamond-shaped), but I am having a hell of a time tracking down a precise statement of this idea.  More specifically, my question is this one:

**Question**: Under what conditions on $w_k$ is the distribution $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} P$ purely a function of the $\ell_2$ (i.e., Euclidean) distance?

In other words, how do you take a walk around Manhattan but end up with a distribution that is "round" instead of diamond-shaped?  If you can't get something that's purely a function of the Euclidean distance, how close can you get?  Can you get something that looks like a Gaussian?  Etc.

References are appreciated as long as they are relevant to this *specific* question -- I am not just looking to read about Pólya for the $n$th time! :-)

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand in what sense the distribution is diamond-shaped. The bulk of the probability is roughly circularly arranged, although on the lattice. Only exponentially small wisps fill out a diamond shape instead. So, in what sense are you concentrating on the exponentially small parts?

Comment: Nope, it's not just exponentially small wisps -- the proof is just too big for the margins. :-) But if you want to see what happens, fix $n$ and consider the ratio $\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty w_k P_k / w_n P_n$ for the weights I gave.  Then take the log as $t$ goes to zero; you'll see that the resulting function depends only on the graph distance.

Comment: If I fix $n=2$, the result of exponentially decreasing weights in that formula is to concentrate on the positive probabilities of smallest $k \gt n$, $k=4$, and the ratio between $P_4$ and $P_2$ is not constant on points of equal graph distance. Specifically, $P_2(2,0) = P_4(2,0) = 1/16$ but $P_2(1,1) = 1/8 \ne P_4(1,1)=3/32.$ 

Comment: Sorry -- let me be more clear.  Consider a node at a graph distance $n$ from the origin.  The first $n-1$ terms in the sum $\sum_{k=0}^\infty w_k P_k$ are zero (since no random walk of length $n-1$ reaches the node of interest).  But evaluate the ratio defined above *at node $i$*.  As $t$ goes to zero, this ratio goes to zero.  Hence the only term contributing to the distribution at $i$ is the $n$th term, which up to a constant looks like $(4t/1+4t)^n P_k^i$.  Take the log of this quantity and you get $n \log (4t/1+4t) + \log(P_k^i)$.  But as $t$ goes to zero the first term dominates...

Comment: ..and hence the (log of the) solution is proportional to just $n$, the graph distance.  (I should also mention that I have performed this experiment numerically and you do indeed recover the diamond-shaped graph distance.  This is not merely a guess!!)

Comment: You are taking the logarithm of something you intentionally weighted by an exponential, and then you discard the constant terms, so that all you see is whether the probability is positive not the values of the distribution. The result is that you are concentrating on the microscopic parts of the distribution $P_n$ instead of where the CLT says the bulk of the distribution is. Note that your question actually asks something quite different. Perhaps some set of weights will make the probability of reaching $(3,4)$ equal to the probability of reaching $(5,0)$. You might need negative weights.

Comment: Correct -- exponentially-decaying weights (as given above) illustrate the fact that if the weights decay too quickly then the central limit theorem does not take over and the solution looks like a function of the $\ell_1$ distance instead of the $\ell_2$ distance.  I'm not sure why you say the bulk of the distribution gets ignored -- the quantity $r_t = \sum_{k=n+1} w_k P_k / w_n Pn$ describes the relative size of the first nonzero term (in the denominator) to the remaining terms (in the numerator).  But since this quantity goes to zero as $t \rightarrow 0$, the bulk must be in the $n$th term.

Comment: The probabilities don't look like a function of the $\ell_1$ distance, except when you forget their magnitudes and only pay attention to whether they are positive, which is what you are doing. 

Comment: The question you asked above leads to some interesting questions, such as how to prove that the probability of ending at $(5,0)$ is greater than or equal to the probability of ending at $(4,3)$ for all lengths or positive weights. However, the study of when the probability is positive is not deep. 

Comment: I'm not sure why you say that.  There are two observations here, as $t$ goes to zero: 1. that only one term in the sum is significant, and 2. the magnitude of that term depends only on n.  Where am I ignoring magnitude?

Comment: (Also, please remember that this fact has been confirmed numerically.)

Comment: As I said, you are ignoring the actual values of $P_n$ (which are not close to constant on $x+y=n$). Your procedure only identifies the support of the distribution, which is trivial. I'm done.

Comment: The values of $P_n$ are ignored only in the sense that they become insignificant as $t$ goes to zero.  In other words, $n \log (4t/(1+4t))$ can be made arbitrarily larger than $\log(P_k^i)$ because the latter does not depend on $t$.  Another way of saying this is that the values of $P_k$ are not being ignored; it's just that they are basically noise relative to the rapidly decaying coefficients that precede them.

I think its a shame that long discussions on MO are implicitly received as argumentation -- I am very appreciative that you have taken the time to discuss this question with me. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the decay rate has much to do with it. Instead, the more time passes, the more Gaussian-shaped the function becomes. Indeed, suppose we let $w_k=1$ if $k=\lfloor C h^{-2}\rfloor $ and $0$ otherwise. Then by the Central Limit Theorem, the distribution approaches a Gaussian, and thus in the limit depends entirely on the $l^2$ norm.

Comment: Yeah, I think we're on the same page -- allowing more time to pass is equivalent to putting larger weights on larger values of $k$.  So if the weights decay slowly then the central limit theorem will take over.  (And if they decay quickly, it won't!)